# How to bind typeahead selection to input fields

Tags: angularjs

I have a modal that is for creating a new Job. There is a typeahead input to search for the related Customer. When I select a Customer from that list I need the properties to populate input fields. I made a plunkr but I can't get the typeahead to work.
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/acUifP4viuu9Whz3ciSW?p=preview)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="CustomerName"
  typeahead="job.Customers[0].CustomerName for job in jobArray  | filter:$viewValue"
   placeholder="Enter Customer" typeahead-on-select="selectedCustomer = $item;">


<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">C. Name</span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="CustomerName"
         typeahead="job.Customers[0].CustomerName for job in jobArray  | filter:$viewValue"
         placeholder="Enter Customer" typeahead-on-select="selectedCustomer = $item;">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon">C. Address</span>
         <input ng-model="CustomerAddress" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The plunkr you've created does not include ui.bootstrap where the `typeahead` directive is defined in.

Comment: ok, i got it in there, still no luck though?  http://plnkr.co/edit/acUifP4viuu9Whz3ciSW?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `ng-app="testApp"` declaration.

`typeahead` attribute should look like this:

```
typeahead="customer.customerName for customer in customers | filter:$viewValue"
```

Not sure what you wanted to achieve with `job.Customers[0].CustomerName for job in customers`.

Lastly I can only guess but I think you wan't to be able to enter customers data both through typeahead and inputs below right? If that's the case you should change the `typeahead-on-select` to

```
typeahead-on-select="selectCustomer($item)"
```

and add `selectCustomer` in your controller:

```
$scope.selectCustomer = function(customer){
  $scope.customerName = customer.customerName;
  $scope.customerAddress = customer.customerAddress;
};
```

See updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u3sK5iyHIHTi5g9u6m3B?p=preview).